# Copy a list conditionally C#

Tags: c#, wpf, list, model, clone

I have a List: zephyrPatientDataList
with a much simplified model:

```
public class zephyrPatientDataList
    {
        public List<zephyrPatientData> patients { get; set; }
    
        
    }

    public class zephyrPatientData
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public int ClaimID { get; set; }
        public string ChemistID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }        

        public List<zDispenseScriptData> scripts{get;set;}        


    }

public class zDispenseScriptData 
    {
        public bool claimItem  { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        
}
```

This is a list bound to a datagrid.
The list shows a Patient and then scripts (prescription medication) that the patient has listed.

From these I have a checkbox for each script (bound to [claimItem] (bool))

I'm getting the user to check the scripts for each patient.

After this I need to upload the scripts to my API.

I have 2 options:

- upload all scripts (could be 200-300) scripts over maybe 10-20 patients.

OR

- create a list of patients and scripts which are marked as

> claimItem = TRUE

I have tried to create a copy of the current list (patientList => uploadPatientList)

Then I tried iterating through the uploadPatientList and removing all scripts which were claimItem = FALSE.

```
foreach (var newPatient in newList.patients)
            {
                if(newPatient.scripts != null){                    
                    
                    for (int i = newPatient.scripts.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
                    {
                        if (!newPatient.scripts[i].claimItem)
                        {
                            newPatient.scripts.Remove(newPatient.scripts[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }               
            }
```

The issue with this (as I found out) is that since they are based on the same memory object, my original list is thus changed.
The issue here is that the data shown to the patient now changes to only show checked items.

How do I "clone" a list and then remove items OR create a list but only with the

> myList.patients.scripts which have claimItem = true?

Comment: 1. Create a new list. 2. Conditionally add items to it.

Comment: Thanks @DiplomacyNotWar .  SO I did try adding all patients from the original List, however it obviously auto adds all scripts too.
I couldn't figure out how to..
Go to each patient, check if it has a claimItem TRUE script, then add that script and the patient details without adding ALL scripts.

Comment: You'll need to copy the objects involved keeping the parts you want. You essentially want a _"deep copy"_ with some parts removed. There isn't really a magic bullet for this in C#.

Comment: Thanks @DiplomacyNotWar I'lll have to figure something out then.  Might be easier to parse in Nodejs

Comment: If you're copying objects around often enough (e.g. between Models, ViewModels, DTOs), you want to use an auto mapping library where you can specify some rules. `AutoMapper` is probably the most popular/mature. There are also other lighter ones if you look around.

Answer (score 1):

Add a list to zephyrPatientData that is just the claimed scripts

```cs
    public class zephyrPatientData
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public int ClaimID { get; set; }
        public string ChemistID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }        

        private List<zDispenseScriptData> _scripts
        public List<zDispenseScriptData> scripts
        { 
          get => _scripts
          set
          {
             _scripts = value;
             claimedScripts = value.Where(s => s.claimItem).ToList();
          } 
         }

         public List<zDispenseScriptData> claimedScripts { get; private set; }
    }
```

With an MVVM approach you also could let the view models maintain the claimed list for you by noting when claimItem changes to true and adding themselves to a list of claimed scripts.

Comment: awesome, i really like that apporach.
I'm still learning MVVM so just haven't made that step yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Linq :
if new List data just for read, it's ok
because , "ToList()" will new a List.

```
List<zDispenseScriptData> NewList = YourList.Where(p=>p.claimItem == true).ToList();
```

and maybe you just make a struct instead of class , it's copy by value naturally like this:

```
public struct zephyrPatientData { //.... }
```